# Logging to stderr and stdout golang Google Cloud Platform

Tags: go, logging, google-cloud-platform

Currently running a go service on GCP however in the logs viewer every message is treated as an error.

Is there a generally advised way of logging to stderr and stdout depending on the log level. Ie errors to stderr and anything else to stdout.

I'm currently using the [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) package and have come across this implementation. Other ways i see achieving this while still using the same package is to pass the logger to each package that needs it or to create a global log object, neither of which i am too keen on.

https://github.com/microsoft/fabrikate/pull/252/commits/bd24d62d7c2b851ad6e7b36653eb0a6dc364474b#diff-ed0770fdbf87b0c6d536e33a99a8df9c

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stackdriver library package for GoLang:

```
go get -u cloud.google.com/go/logging
```

Then you can use StandardLogger:

```
// Sample stdlogging writes log.Logger logs to the Stackdriver Logging.
package main

import (
        "context"
        "log"

        "cloud.google.com/go/logging"
)

func main() {
        ctx := context.Background()

        // Sets your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
        projectID := "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"

        // Creates a client.
        client, err := logging.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
        }
        defer client.Close()

        // Sets the name of the log to write to.
        logName := "my-log"

        logger := client.Logger(logName).StandardLogger(logging.Info)

        // Logs "hello world", log entry is visible at
        // Stackdriver Logs.
        logger.Println("hello world")
}
```

Here you can find [documentation on Google Cloud website](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/go)

Update:

---

Alternatively you could give a try [GCP formatter for logrus](https://github.com/znly/logrus-gce)

This will not tie your app to Google Cloud Platform. However, it does not mean that on another platform you will not need to change your code to format output.

Using StackDriver library is the recommended solution for Google Cloud.

Comment: Hi Pawel, Ideally i'd prefer not to tie in the logging to GCP

Comment: This is the recommended solution.

Comment: If you want to use stack driver yes, however i'm talking about the log viewer on GCP  and don't want to couple the application to stack driver logging

Comment: You could give a try [GCP formatter for logrus](https://github.com/znly/logrus-gce), however your code would need change. And I did not test this solution.

Comment: I did update the answer, please accept it if it worked for you, for better visibility for another users.

Comment: So, you say Google "recommends" to bring over a debt of over **two thousand packages** just to be able to filter logs by severity. (See `go mod graph`) I would be concerned about influx of security vulnerabilities and the future impact of patching them.

Answer (score 2):

We use https://github.com/rs/zerolog with the following method called in our Init() method to setup the logging options at global level:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
    "github.com/rs/zerolog/log"
    "os"
)
// initializeLogging sets up the logging configuration for the service.
// Invoke this method in your Init() method.
func initializeLogging() {
    // Set logging options for production development
    if os.Getenv("ENV") != "DEV" {
        // change the level field name to ensure these are parsed correctly in Stackdriver
        zerolog.LevelFieldName = "severity"
        // UNIX Time is faster and smaller than most timestamps
        zerolog.TimeFieldFormat = zerolog.TimeFormatUnix
    } else {
        // Set logging options for local development
        log.Logger = log.Output(zerolog.ConsoleWriter{Out: os.Stderr})
        zerolog.SetGlobalLevel(zerolog.DebugLevel)
    }
    
    // Example log
    log.Info().Msg("This is how you log at Info level")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the https://github.com/apsystole/log. You can swap either `log` and `logrus` imports for it. It is a small zero-dependency module, hence much lighter than logrus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging from a process running in a GKE pod, and you want your logs to be ingested via the stdout stream, then just use the standard Google golang logging library, but configure it to write to stdout.

```
    client, err := logging.NewClient(context.Background(), "projects/"+project)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    log := client.Logger(logName, logging.RedirectAsJSON(nil))
    return &Logger{
        client: client,
        log:    log,
    }, nil
```